# Given three points on a tetrahedron, Find the 4th

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry

If you have an equilateral triangle in 3D space, where all the sides are of length 1, there are two points that you could use to form a tetrahedron. One floating out in front of the triangle, and one behind it. Given the coordinates of the three known vertices, how would you calculate either of the possible fourth vertices?

I would really appreciate it if you can show how to do it with the [Processing vector class definition](http://processing.org/reference/PVector.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Average your three points to get the center of the triangle:

```
center = (a + b + c) / 3
```

Calculate the normal vector by taking the cross product of two of the sides:

```
normal = (c - a) x (b - a)
```

Normalize the normal vector (make it of unit length):

```
unit_normal = normal / |normal|
```

Scale the normal by the height of regular tetrahedron:

```
scaled_normal = unit_normal * sqrt(2/3)
```

Now, your two points are:

```
top = center + scaled_normal
bottom = center - scaled_normal
```

Answer (score 3):

`(a + b + c)/3` (centre of the triangle)

`+/- ((a-b) x (b-c)` (cross product of two sides of the triangle, hence perpendicular to both)

`* some constant or other)` (the height of a regular tetrahedron divided by the length of that cross product, the length being 1 * 1 * sin(60 degrees) = sqrt(3)/2)

This can probably be simplified.

[Edit: height is sqrt(2/3), so the constant is `2*sqrt(2)`]

[Second edit: any fourth point not in the plane of the first three forms a tetrahedron. ITYM a *regular* tetrahedron ;-)]

Answer (score 1):

Since, 3D has never been my interest, I guess I can only provide a way to do this, rather than exact coordinates.

> A point which lies at a distance of
>   sqrt(2/3) from the centroid of the
>   triangle and on a line perpendicular
>   to the plane formed by the triangle
>   and containing the centroid.